# Metrizability of the space $C^0([0, T], \mathcal G)$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Given $T>0$, let us denote by $\mathcal G$ the set of the Borel measures $\nu$ on $\mathbb R^d$ bounded by a constant $G$ (i.e. $\int_{\mathbb R^d}d\nu\leq G$) and endowed with the weak* convergence topology (see [The wide or weak* topology](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures#The_wide_or_weak.7F.27.22.60UNIQ-MathJax41-QINU.60.22.27.7F_topology) what I mean for *weak* * *convergence topology*) and, if necessary, with finite $p^{\text{th}}$ moment.

I want to know if the space $C^0([0, T], \mathcal G)$ is metrizable.

I know that it depends on the metrizability of the space $\mathcal G$. Indeed, once $\mathcal G$ is metrizable, $C^0([0, T], \mathcal G)$ has a natural topology and a natural metric, which is the sup norm.

In the web page [above](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures#The_wide_or_weak.7F.27.22.60UNIQ-MathJax41-QINU.60.22.27.7F_topology), it is written that the weak* convergence topology is metrizable but I do not know if it can be applied to the particular space $\mathcal G$ too. Moreover it is not specified how could be the metric (Wasserstein?).

So my question is: is $\mathcal G$ metrizable? If not, what are the conditions for which $\mathcal G$ can be metrizable? And what is the metric?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Levy-Prohorov metric $d$ metrizes weak* convergence  of   Borel probability measures on $\mathbb R^{d}$ [ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy%E2%80%93Prokhorov_metric ]. We can metrize $\mathcal G$ by $D(\mu, \nu)=|\mu_1 (\mathbb R^{d})-\nu_1 (\mathbb R^{d})+|d(\mu, \nu)|$ where $\mu_1=\frac {\mu} {\mu (\mathbb R^{d})}$ and $\nu_1=\frac {\nu} {\nu (\mathbb R^{d})}$.

Comment: Ok, thank you. The Wikipedia page says that it metrizes the weak convergence topology, not the weak* convergence one. Is it the same? Moreover, is it true also for bounded Borel measures (in the sense above)?

Comment: Probabilists say weak convergence for weak* convergence! Also, I have edited my answer. @Redeldio

Comment: Ok, thank you. For the second question? In the Wikipedia page it is not written that the Borel measures can be bounded (in the sense above). Does it hold anyway?

Comment: @Redeldio The metric I have defined does give weak* convergence. You only need the fact that $\mu_n \to \mu$  iff $\mu_n (\mathbb R^{d}) \to \mu (\mathbb R^{d})$ and $\frac {\mu_n} {\mu_n (\mathbb R^{d})} \to \frac {\mu } { \mu (\mathbb R^{d})}$

Comment: Ok, right. Last question: can it be metrizable by the Wasserstein metric too? What are the conditions for which this can be possible? Thank you

Comment: @Redeldio As mentioned in the following link convergence in Wassersetin metric is not equivalent to weak* convergence: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstein_metric

Comment: Ok for the Wasserstein metric. I have a doubt on the first question. Are you sure that the Levy-Prokhorov metric metrizes $\mathcal G$? I do not have Borel probability measures but only bounded Borel measures..

Comment: @Redeldio If $\mu, \mu_n$ are finite measures on $X=\mathbb R^{d}$ then $\mu_n \to mu$ in weak* topology iff $\mu_n(X) \to \mu(X)$ and the probability measures $\frac {\mu_n} {\mu_n(X)}$ converge to  the probability measure $\frac {\mu} {\mu(x)}$ in weak* topology. This is immediate from definition of weak* convergence.